# Inserting removed data back into a vector, at its original location, in R

Tags: r, vector, indexing

In R, I have a vector, and I want to remove certain elements, apply a computation to that filtered array, and then insert the removed elements back in again.

For example, if I want to remove `NaN`s, and then apply `cumsum`:

```r
> v = c(1, NaN, 2, NaN, 3)
> (nans = is.nan(v))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> (filtered = v[!nans])
[1] 1 2 3
> (summed = cumsum(filtered))
[1] 1 3 6
```

Now, what I want is to insert the `NaN`s back into the vector in their original locations, giving me `c(1, NaN, 3, NaN, 6)`.

The naive way to do this is:

```r
> summed[nans] = v[nans]
> summed
[1]   1 NaN   6 NaN  NA
```

However obviously this is wrong. Because the indicies of `summed` are different to `v`, I can't simply re-use the `nans` logical vector.

Note that this is just a simplified example. In my real problem, the removed values aren't all the same as each other (`NaN`), and I also don't know how many values will be removed nor how long `v` is.

So my question is, how can I reverse the original logical indexing I did when I filtered the vector, and get back the processed array, but with `NaN`s inserted again? I'm happy with any core R or library solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
v[!nans] = summed
v
#[1]   1 NaN   3 NaN   6
```

`!nans` reverses the boolean vector giving the index where value is not `NaN` and `summed` is the vector to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[<-` to reinsert `NaN`:

```
"[<-"(rep(NaN, length(v)), !nans, summed)
#[1]   1 NaN   3 NaN   6
```

In fact here I create a vector of `NaN` and insert the values of `summed`.

Alternatively the `NaN` from `v` could be used like:

```
"[<-"(v, !nans, summed)
#[1]   1 NaN   3 NaN   6
```